# how can i normalize lbp histograms obtained from patches with different size

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working in face recognition, and I'm trying to compare histograms of different regions of the face of several test subjects, but the issue is that the region from where the histograms are calculated have different sizes.I need to normalize the histogram, and i don't have any idea about how i can do it.

Comment: Divide by the total. After that the sum of all bins of a single histogram is always 1.

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)

Comment: just `normalize(hist,hist);` (you don't need to know the size, and it does not matter)

Comment: which normalize function? opencv normalize function? i just dont understand very well what this function does.

Answer (score 0):

is it Local Binary Pattern histogram?
like this one? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns
I think.. does LBP feature has a same size histogram between a different window size?

Comment: The regions have different sizes but all histograms are same size.. right?
if you want to compare between historgrams not regions then use normalize function of opencv
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html
I can't compile right now with opencv.. so you can find how normalize() function works from above link.

Comment: yes, they are uniform histograms, all have 59 bins... but the regions, from the were calculated are different size...

Comment: oops it seems that i bother you I'm not an native English speaker so.. just want to make it sure that I do understand your question :) by the way, normalize() function helps you before comparing them.

Comment: i feel u bro, I'm not either a native English speaker so don't worry jajaja.... but thanks for the info, it is helpful....